# I want to adjust the size of the grouped GridHelper using the GUI

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to change the size of the grid using the GUI, but it doesn't work.
How can I resize it?
I am creating it by following the steps below.

```
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x222222);

let group = new THREE.Group();
scene.add( group );
                
let g=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xc0c0c0});
let size=1.0;
let step=5.0;
for(let i=0;i<6;i++){
 for(let j=1;j<2;j+=0.2){
  let grid1 =new THREE.GridHelper(size,step,g,g);
  grid1.myid=i;
  grid1.rotation.x=0;
  grid1.position.y=j;
  grid1.position.z=0;
  group.add(grid1); 
 }  
}
for(let k=0;k<6;k++){
 for(let n=-0.5;n<0.7;n+=0.2){
  let grid2 =new THREE.GridHelper(size,step,g,g);
  grid2.myid=k;
  grid2.rotation.x=Math.PI/2;
  grid2.position.y=1.5;
  grid2.position.z=n;
  group.add(grid2); 
  }             
 }
```

The GUI looks like this.

```
const params = {
　size:1.0,
　visible: true
};
```

```
const gui = new GUI( { width: 300 } );
gui.add( params ,'size' ,0.1,2.0).step(0.1).onChange( function(val){
    group.size=val;://I want to resize here
});
gui.add( params, 'visible' ).onChange( function(visible){
    group.visible=visible;//Can be shown or hidden
} );
gui.open();
```

The program can run. However, when I touch the size bar, I don't see any change in the size of the grid.

Comment: There are some undefined variables (`scene`, `group1`, `GUI`), and there's an extra `let` in your code. Is your code working? Can you see the grid? The reason I'm asking - when I try to replicate your issue in jsfiddle, I can see the controls, but no grid.

Comment: I am sorry! That definition is a typo! I got mixed with another program.We will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this part:

```
gui.add( params ,'size' ,0.1,2.0).step(0.1).onChange( function(val){
    group.size=val;://I want to resize here
});
```

into this:

```
gui.add( params ,'size' ,0.1,2.0).step(0.1).onChange( function(val){
    group.scale.set(val,val,val); //I want to resize here
});
```

The reason for this is that your `group` is a 3D object, so you need to change its `scale` property (which is a `Vector`) for x, y, and z. Your GUI scaling slider is outputting just a single number, and since you (presumably) want to scale up and down proportionally, you need to assign your slider's value to all three dimensions.

Hope this helps.